# Error while installng Red Hat OS for Dual Boot over Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to have 2 OS installed on my HDD (80GB).

I installed Windows 7 first.

Then booting from the DVD drive I launch the RHEL setup and in the partitioning phase I get the following errors:

[image: First error]

[image: Second error]

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 and Linux can be installed on a 80 GB drive.

I would shrink Windows 7 partition to say 60 GB. 
So in the 20 GB left Linux can be installed.

To shrink Windows 7 partition you can use Disk Management -
click on Start, Run: diskmgmt.msc
Right click on Windows 7 partition and select "Shrink Volume"

When installing Linux you have two options:

1. Install Linux boot loader (GRUB) to MBR - here GRUB will have control over the dual-booting and the dual-boot will be created automatically when installing Linux.
2. Install Linux boot loader to partition - here Windows will have control over the dual-booting but you have to manually add a boot entry in Windows BCD for booting Linux.
   You can use Visual BCD Editor to add a boot entry for Linux - see [VBCDE-HowTo-Section 8](http://boyans.net/VBCD_HowTo.html) how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

How big is your Windows partition?  If your Windows partition consumes the entire HDD, then you're going to need to shorten it and create free space on your hard disk first.  Once you've done that, you should be able to direct the RHEL install to use the free space.

Also, 80GB is barely enough space for a Windows 7 install.  If you want a dual-boot system, then you're going to need a larger hard drive.  I dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on a 160GB system, and I'm pressed for space.